# Grails 3 : GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Tags: hibernate, grails3, grails-3.3

Some read queries fail one in ten times with the following message:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

The endpoint itself just calls Myclass.findById(myInstanceId), so it is a plugin/library/framework issue.

Having read [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/solved-org-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-could-not-prepare-statement/) that it could be due to conflicting dependencies with hibernate, here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3'
    compile group: 'org.jdbi', name: 'jdbi', version: '2.78'
    compile "co.freeside.jdbi-time:jdbi-time:1.1"
    compile "org.eurekanetwork.libs:errorhandling:0.3.2"
    compile "org.eurekanetwork.plugin:render-command-errors:0.1.4"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.3'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq-native:3.3.0'
    compile 'javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:4.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy', version: '1.6.4'
    compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.9'

    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.eurekanetwork.libs:grails3-test-libraries:0.0.4"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
[timestamp=Mon Jan 14 15:03:20 CET 2019] [hostname=polydeuces] 
[logtype=JAVASTACK_TRACE] [javaclass=class     org.eurekanetwork.project.ProjectParticipantController] [loglevel=CRITICAL]     [clientip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] [user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.6.0]     [exception=org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement] [stacktrace=[org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47), org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111), org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182),
```

2019-01-14 15:03:35.594 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Failed to validate a newly established connection.
    STACKTRACE: 
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.5.Final.jar:5.1.5.Final]

NB: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597346/failed-to-validate-a-newly-established-connection-with-grails-3-3-5), similar to my problem. Setting the testOnBorrow setting to false seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597346/failed-to-validate-a-newly-established-connection-with-grails-3-3-5).

Setting the testOnBorrow setting to false resolves the issue.